# JQuery how to capture enter key or double click on select->option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say i have this html:

```
<select size="6">
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
    <option>option 4</option>
</select>
```

and this is my js:

```
$('select').on('dblclick',function(){
   alert('something');
});
```

it's working fine when i double click on an item, but it's not working after navigating using UP/Down keys and then pressing Enter key. what is the solution?

**I have used size attrib in select so i have a list now**

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/silverlight/ce3r5jgd/)**

Comment: why don't you simply use change event??

Comment: cause it calls function by navigating. and it's not what I looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about this code ?

```
$('select').on('dblclick keyup',function(e){
    if(e.which == 13 || e.type == 'dblclick') alert('something');
  });
```

Comment: So it cant be with one listener ? i have to use `dblclick` and keypress same time ?

Comment: it's good but maybe with this manipulation: `  $('select').on('dblclick keyup',function(e){
    if(e.which == 13 || e.type == 'dblclick') alert('something');
  });`

Comment: great @Omid, you revised me that implementation syntax

Comment: :) i'm glad i helped to u.